# SSDT2012 copy csv file to deploy server

Tags: sql-server, deployment, sql-server-data-tools, dacpac

I am using SSDT2012 to deploy a database project. I have static data that I want to populate but it is in a .csv file. I added it to the project but can't see a way to copy over to the server temp folder or something similar.
I tried adding

Thanks for the help!

EDIT: I have been looking at [Deployment Contributors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn268597%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) but it is still not a solution. The need to actually have everyone copy the Contributor onto their machines and having to maintain that and bug fix it; it is not a desirable approach.

Comment: Does it have to stay as a CSV?  why not a post-deploy insert script?

Comment: it has 2000 lines. It could be an insert, but I need an elegant solution as it might grow/ might be multiple similar files in the future.

Comment: Why would **SQL Server** Data Tools support the "deployment" of CSV files? What were you going to do with the file once you got it to the server in any case?

Comment: Load the data in the DB to seed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommended approach to dealing with static data is to use merge statements in the pre or post deploy scripts:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssdt/archive/2012/02/02/including-data-in-an-sql-server-database-project.aspx

2000 lines is quite a lot but sql can easily handle it.

Getting your 2000 line csv into a merge statement by hand will obviously be a royal pain so you can use the Sql import wizard to get it into a table (basically just deploy it somewhere) and then you can deploy sp_generate_merge to create the merge statement which you can then put into your post-deploy script:

https://github.com/readyroll/generate-sql-merge

If you are going to use merge statements then regardless of whether you automatically generate the script or not, I would really recommend using this blog from Alex Whittles to help understand how they work as they can be quite confusing to start with:

http://www.purplefrogsystems.com/blog/2011/12/introduction-to-t-sql-merge-basics/

Finally you should be careful when you remove items from your static data, if you have other tables with foreign keys into the data and you remove an item that the child tables depend on the merge statement would fail so you should make sure you go ahead and deal with any possible issues in the pre/post deployment script before running the merge. These should be re-runnable.

Ed

Comment: While I do agree with your response and it is elegantly formulated, I do wonder, is there no way to copy that file from this type o project? Seems like it should support that out of the box. My problem with this approach is that I will end up with a post deploy script of thousands (if not tens of thousands) of lines. I do use "the recommended" way for a lot of other stuff but the need for this file and some other like this in the future made me realize that this is not a good way of doing it.

Comment: If you have lots of static data in different tables you could manage it by using the post deploy script to do things like using openrowset to read the csv file into sql - once it is in sql (a staging or temp table) you can do a merge to the actual table (example: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/5869d247-f0a0-4224-80b3-ff2e414be402/how-to-read-csv-file-in-sql-server-2005-using-openrowset-function?forum=sqldataaccess) + thanks for saying my answer was elegant!

Comment: That is what I am trying to do. I want to copy that file over on the server, from deployment, and have the PostDeploy script run the import. I can't manage to get the file on the server when publishing. As I said I do use that approach for a lot of small things, but this new situation just tipped the scales and I don't want to do the same thing.

Comment: In that case what I would consider doing is writing a small .net app that wraps the dacpac deployment api and allows you to do an import of the csv from wherever you are. See this on how to do the deploy: http://blogs.msmvps.com/deborahk/deploying-a-dacpac-with-dacfx-api/ importing a csv file is pretty easy (use the vb.net TextFieldParser from c#), that way you won't have to copy any files anywhere you don't control.

Comment: Haven't done it myself, but I wonder if you could supplement with the Post build event command line https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/42x5kfw4.aspx

Comment: Thank you so much for the input, I will be using this approach for this case but would still like  to have my option as well!